# PhpMyAdmin slipping <style>html{display:none;}</style> into <head> tag after adding https and cloudflare?

Tags: ssl, https, phpmyadmin, cloudflare

I bought a comodo tls certificate and successfully added it to my website running on Arch Linux and NGINX.

The main homepage displays fine.

The phpMyAdmin directory that was working prior to adding cloudflare and https still displays, and would show everything I assume, except for this pesky bit of html which seems to be being implanted into the  tag for some reason:

```
<style>html{display:none;}</style>
```

Has anybody else come across this phenomenon before?

PHPMYADMIN + CLOUDFLARE = display none?

Comment: It's not a proper solution (which I suppose is why I'm posting as a comment rather than an answer), but I'm relatively confident this isn't phpMyAdmin doing this. You should ask your host support folks if they have any thoughts. Did they provide the phpMyAdmin installation or did you download and install it to your web root yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was cloudflare doing something that phpmyadmin didn't like apparantly.

Accessing my direct.domain.com/phpmyadmin link works as domain.com/phpmyadmin used to.

The 'direct' subdomain is a cloudflare-free subdomain by default as specified in the cloudflare DNS settings.